# Howto prevent eclipse from line wrapping in XML and HTML files?

Tags: xml, eclipse, word-wrap

Is it possible to completely stop Eclipse from line wrapping XML and HTML files? It is easy to do this i.e. for java files, but I couldn't find similar settings for XML and HTML files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: the word/line wrapping in eclipse is a "sore" topic, since 2003, as this massively voted [**bug 35779**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779)

As [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho) mentions, there is only [hard-wrapping](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779#c16) (at a specify length)

[alt text http://www.openengsb.org/images/codingstyle/eclipse-xml-settings.png](http://www.openengsb.org/images/codingstyle/eclipse-xml-settings.png)

Reminder:

> - **Soft** will just warp the text at the right
>     window border without adding new line numbers (so there are gaps in the list of
>     numbers when you enable them).
>     This mode is useful for HTML and the like.
>     A nice feature of the soft wrap is automatic indentation: If there is
>     whitespace at the beginning of the line, the wrapped lines are automatically
>     indented by the same amount.
> - **Hard** will add and remove newlines in the text as you type to balance the width.
>     Here, you can usually set a margin (80 characters, for example).
>     This is useful for READMEs and other stuff that will be read in a terminal.

Answer (score 47):

`Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor`, and set `line-width` there
(Do accordingly for HTML, under `Web > HTML files`)

Comment: 999 seems to be the maximum and 0 does not mean off, but really 0!!  I wish we could just turn it off. Anyway, just FYI.

Comment: 999 should be enough though.. :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. :-) Maybe a tiny performance boost, but I think that can be ignored too.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the settings for XML formatting are in the IDE-wide preferences tab and apparently they cannot be set on a per-project basis.

I want to point out that what is really annoying is the wrapping of "free text" between elements like in:

`<element>some free text</element>`

That's really an inconvenience when dealing with the pattern format in logback.xml files, for instance.

I just found out that Eclipse won't format that bit if I enclose the text between `<![CDATA[..]]>`.
For instance:

`<pattern><![CDATA[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%X{host}|%X{ip}|%X{user}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n]]></pattern>`

Just wanted to share that.

Comment: pattern escape `<![CDATA[` works like a charm! `]]>` even in Genuitec MyEclipse Workbench