# Eclipse formatting of Spring Expression Langugage

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatter, spring-el

When formatting spring bean xml files in Eclipse 3.7, the formatter can wrap lines in the middle of a spring expression language value. For example,

```
<util:list>
  <value>#T(com.mycompany.mypackage.AClass).someStaticMethodHere('param1','param2','Some long string parameter')</value>
</util:list>
```

This block might end up looking like

```
<util:list>
  <value>#T(com.mycompany.mypackage.AClass).someStaticMethodHere('param1','param2',
'Some long string parameter')</value>
</util:list>
```

Which becomes an invalid Spring EL expression.

Is there a way to selectively exclude this? Or to prevent the formatter from doing this? It makes working with Spring EL a pain if I can't format the file.

Comment: May it be, your maximum line width is set to a small value? This would cause such a wrap. Taking a look at the format settings of the XML Editor reveals no setting to keep element content unwrapped if the length is greater than the maximum line width.

Comment: I could do that, but I guess I was just looking for a more general solution as to how to prevent this from happening since I might not want all of my lines to be that long, just the ones with the expression language values in them.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005929/howto-prevent-eclipse-from-line-wrapping-in-xml-and-html-files. You can do it just for XML-Editor by setting `Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor`, and set `line-width` there. This should solve it the half way.