# Eclipse's Formatter Messes Up Command Line Arguments in our POM

Tags: eclipse, maven, format, pom.xml, surefire

We have to pass arguments to surefire in our pom file. Invariably, someone comes in and formats the file and the arguments line gets wrapped and the project breaks. I could not find a way to tell it hands off. I guess I could also look for a way to configure surefire in some other way, but that is suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap command line argument into XML's CDATA construction, eclipse won't break it:

```
<argLine><![CDATA[-X -Y -Z]]></argLine>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the pom file is an XML file, you just need to configure the formatting of an XML. Since you cannot turn wrap off, you would just need to set the max width to an insanely large number.

See this semi-related question: [Howto prevent eclipse from line wrapping in XML and HTML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005929/howto-prevent-eclipse-from-line-wrapping-in-xml-and-html-files)